# How to serialize MAC address in embedded Linux product?

Tags: embedded-linux, mac-address, device-tree

Apparently the current trend in kernel (correct me if I got that wrong) is to embed it in Device Tree.

This is testified by several drovers calling

```
const void *of_get_mac_address(struct device_node *np)
{
    const void *addr;

    addr = of_get_mac_addr(np, "mac-address");
    if (addr)
        return addr;

    addr = of_get_mac_addr(np, "local-mac-address");
    if (addr)
        return addr;

    addr = of_get_mac_addr(np, "address");
    if (addr)
        return addr;

    return of_get_mac_addr_nvmem(np);
}
```

in the initialization routine.

Question is:

What is the "best practice" for serialization in production?

Normal procedure is to have a "programming station" at the end of the production line to load Flash (SPI NOR, in my case) with all needed data; most of it is static, but a small part will need to be "serialized".

In my case this serialized data is loaded in a very small MTD partition.

My current strategy id to retrieve it in the startup phase and modify the (random generated) MAC address (together with other data) using something like `macchanger`.

This, beside being inelegant, means a different address will appear on-line for a short time.

OTOH rebuilding the full .dtb just to change MAC address (and find the right place to dump it) does not look better.

I *do* have better ideas, but, before I set up to reinvent the wheel, I would like to ask if there's some well-established practice to deal with the problem.

Comment: *"Apparently the current trend ... Device Tree"* -- DT is used by only a few architectures, not all.  Otherwise your question seems off-topic.

Comment: @sawdust: AFAIK DT is used by most non-x86 architectures; surely it's used by mine (mips). Could You tell me why question "seems off-topic"? It surely is about programming as I need to program (at the very least by scripting) a suitable serialization strategy. It is true I asked for architectural advice, but that's still part of programming.

Comment: For our laboratory we supply MAC address when we create an image, in which it has been used directly and passed further if needed. But there are different ways, of course, the best of which is to have it simple provided as a (DT/ACPI) property. (There is also NVMEM variant, bit it may increase BoM)

Comment: *"AFAIK DT is used by most non-x86 architectures"* -- There are 25 subdirectories under **arch/** in Linux kernel 5.5.  I can find usage of `of_*` routines in about 7 of those subdirectories.  Granted that's more than a *"few"*, but that number is certainly not close to *'most"*.  Asking for *""best practice" for serialization in production"* sounds like soliciting for opinions on an issue that might only tangentially involve coding.